# Object gets jagged lines after doing free transformation, How to make it smooth?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustration, transform, rotate

When I rotate the object, it is having jagged lines. It was smooth before but I am suddenly facing this problem. The first image is the original one, 2nd one after rotating a bit.

[image: original]

[image: jagged lines]

Comment: Hi Narcissus, welcome to GD.SE, it's impossible to find out what the problem is if you do not put in the question or in the tags the program you use.

Comment: In Photoshop, I assume? Try different interpolation methods when tree transform is active. I'm guessing you might have nearest neighbor as the interpolation method. Also the biggest eyesore from what I can see is that black bleeding from under the green. That's all thanks to anti-aliasing. If you put the green block in a clipping mask with the black layer, that bleed-through won't happen.

Comment: I used adobe illustrator. This problem is happening suddenly and I'm fairly new to using this software. @Danielillo

Comment: In illustrator. Looking at interpolation methods now. thanks for the reply. @Joonas

Comment: When I see some visual weirdness, the first thing I check is if GPU preview is on. You can see if it's on in the tab or window title. You can switch to CPU preview from: `View > View using CPU`.

Comment: Not solved. Can't figure out what is going wrong. :C @Joonas

Comment: Yea I thought it might not be that. I think for anyone to figure it out, they'd have to take a look at the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have pixel preview mode on, Everything is shown like rasterized. Perfectly vertical and horizontal lines are still ok, but others are jagged.

Goto the View menu and uncheck Pixel Preview.